# Selenium Python unable to click on a select button

Tags: python, selenium, element

I'm practicing my automation skills and trying to automate around the Amazon website. Currently, I'm having issues where my automation test script won't click on the select button so then the drop-down list will display the variety of sizes for its items. Is there any other options I can use so then Selenium can click on the button?

I tried the following method but no luck.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#dropdown_selected_size_name > span > span').click()
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to test:

`//*[@id="dropdown_selected_size_name"]/span/span`.

```
            <option value="-1" id="native_size_name_-1" data-a-id="size_name_-1" selected="">         
                        Select

            </option>

            <option value="0,B01KXHF98M" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_0" data-a-id="size_name_0" data-a-html-content="18 oz (532 ml) Standard Mouth">
                18 oz (532 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>

            <option value="1,B01KXHF626" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_1" data-a-id="size_name_1" data-a-html-content="21 oz (621 ml) Standard Mouth">
                21 oz (621 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>

            <option value="2,B01KXHF34W" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_2" data-a-id="size_name_2" data-a-html-content="24 oz (710 ml) Standard Mouth">
                24 oz (710 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>

            <option value="3,B01N9TFE5L" class="dropdownUnavailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_name_3" data-a-id="size_name_3" data-a-html-content="12 oz (354 ml) Standard Mouth">
                12 oz (354 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>


    </select>
```

additional htmls

```
#variation_size_name > span.twister-dropdown-highlight.transparentTwisterDropdownBorder > span
```

```
            <option value="-1" id="native_size_name_-1" data-a-id="size_name_-1" selected="">  
                        Select    
            </option>

            <option value="0,B01KXHF98M" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_0" data-a-id="size_name_0" data-a-html-content="18 oz (532 ml) Standard Mouth">
                18 oz (532 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>

            <option value="1,B01KXHF626" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_1" data-a-id="size_name_1" data-a-html-content="21 oz (621 ml) Standard Mouth">
                21 oz (621 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>       
            <option value="2,B01KXHF34W" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_2" data-a-id="size_name_2" data-a-html-content="24 oz (710 ml) Standard Mouth">
                24 oz (710 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>

            <option value="3,B01N9TFE5L" class="dropdownUnavailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownUnavailable" id="native_size_name_3" data-a-id="size_name_3" data-a-html-content="12 oz (354 ml) Standard Mouth">
                12 oz (354 ml) Standard Mouth
            </option>


    </select><span tabindex="-1" id="dropdown_selected_size_name" data-a-class="aui-variation  a-fastclick-disable" class="a-button a-button-dropdown aui-variation  a-fastclick-disable" style="min-width: 0%;"><span class="a-button-inner"><span class="a-button-text a-declarative" data-action="a-dropdown-button" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-dropdown-prompt">                                                
                       Select                    
            </span></span><i class="a-icon a-icon-dropdown"></i></span></span></span>
    </span>
```

Element I want to select:
`<a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="{&quot;stringVal&quot;:&quot;1,B01KXHF626&quot;}" id="native_dropdown_selected_size_name_2" class="a-dropdown-link">21 oz (621 ml) Standard Mouth</a>`

Comment: This is not the relevant HTML, please share the html with select and options tags along with your desire output .

Comment: @cruisepandey updated my post with other htmls

Comment: Please define the select tag attributes also !

Comment: and which element you wanna select after clicking on drop down ?

Comment: Try with selector : **span.a-dropdown-container ** instead of  **#dropdown_selected_size_name > span > span**..

Comment: @Nish26 I tried the following selector `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.a-dropdown-container').click()`, i can see it highlights the select button but the drop lists did not display

Comment: @cruisepandey updated my post with the select tag attributes and the element I want to select after it clicks.

Comment: @kav I tried them with C# selenium bindings on chrome version 65  and chromedriver version 2.37 for one of the page on amazon and both the selectors that i suggested worked for me .... Could you provide the url where you are trying this out?

Comment: @Nish26 This is the URL https://www.amazon.com/Hydro-Flask-Insulated-Stainless-Standard/dp/B01KXHF34W/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1523986956&sr=8-3&keywords=hydroflask

Comment: @Nish26 I'm using python 3.6 selenium 3.11.0 on mozilla 52.0.1 Pycharm

Comment: @kav ..I am able to click using above selectors on Firefox 59 with geckodriver 0.20.1....I would recommend upgrading to latest version. Please start a chat or pm me if you need any further help after upgrading.

Comment: @Nish26 Hi Nish, I was able to update my software to Ubuntu 16.04 
geckodriver 0.20.1, firefox 59.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Python 3.6, Pycharm 2016.3, Selenium 3.11.0. So I tried the following code you provided and it still not working. Also how do i start a chat?